# Matlab: Count number of structs that have a specific content

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, count

I'm dealing with Simulink Design Verifier and want to extract some information on my own. Therefore, I want to count the number of Objectives and how much of them have been satisfied.

'Objectives' is a struct itself: Objectives<1x10 struct>

Counting the number of objectives is easy:

```
length(fieldnames(Objectives))
```

The content of 'Objectives' are also structs. Each such struct has the following content:

```
type

status

label
```

Now I want to count how many elements in 'Objectives' satisfy the property

```
'status == Satisfied'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of structs, use the following code:

```
 nnz(strcmp({Objectives.status},'satisfied'))
```

If you have old Matlab version, you can use:

```
 nnz(strmatch('satisfied',{Objectives.status},'exact'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ISMEMBER. Example:

```
%# lets create a sample array-of-structs
v = cellstr( num2str(rand(10,1)>0.5, 'Value %d') );
s = struct('value',v);

%# count number of structs satistying a condition
num = sum( ismember(lower({s.value}), 'value 0') )
```

Note how I am performing case-insensitive comparison by using LOWER function.